# Calling custom Theme() function for form in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, themes, hook

Drupal doesn't call my theme function for my form in my module.

I added the hook_theme in the .module file as this :

```
function agil_theme() {
    return array(
        'agil_list_form' => array(
            'render element' => 'form',
        ),
    );
}
```

where :

- agil is the name of my module (not my theme)
- agil_list_form is the name of my form declaration (chich render with default theme)

I want to call a function to create my own markup, as this one :

```
function theme_agil_list_form($form) {
  $output  = "<table><th><td></td><td>".t('Title')."</td><td>".t('Link')."</td></th>";
    $output .= "<tr><td>";
  $output .= drupal_render($form['name']);
  ...
```

But Drupal is never calling this function... I cleared the cache but nothing..

Where do I miss something ?

I read also this about new theme declaration in Drupal 7 :
http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#hook_theme_render_changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All theme functions in Drupal 7 take a single array argument (usually named as `$vars` or `$variables` by convention), and that array contains the variables/render elements you've declared. The theme function itself would look like this:

```
function theme_agil_list_form($vars) {
  $form = $vars['form'];
  // Now manipulate $form
}
```

Also you need to tell Drupal that your form will be using this theme, by doing this in your form function:

```
$form['#theme'] = 'agil_list_form';
```

Comment: Great. It works. I missed the $form['#theme'] in my form declaration and it was not mentionned in the documentation I read... Thx !